# Get index of first TRUE element of each column of a matrix, but index must be > to n

Tags: r

So I've got a matrix of logical vectors like this :

```
r=10
c=10
m1 <- matrix(runif(r*c)>0.5, r, c)
> m1
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And a vector like this :

```
v1 <- round(runif(10,1,10))
> v1
 [1] 6 5 7 5 5 4 4 2 1 10
```

How can I get the 10 indexes > v1 of first TRUE value of each column of m1 ?

So for this example, I want to get this vector :

```
[1] 9 7 8 NA 6 5 7 3 3 NA
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: please repost your examples with a seed to enable us to reproduce.

Comment: Maurits gave me a good option, but I'll set seed next time, sorry !

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `mapply`. Here is a reproducible example using a fixed random seed.

```
set.seed(2017)
r <- 10
c <- 10
m1 <- matrix(runif(r*c) > 0.5, r, c)    
v1 <- round(runif(10,1,10))   

mapply(function(x, y) { idx <- which(x == TRUE); idx[idx > y][1]}, as.data.frame(m1), v1, USE.NAMES = F)
#[1] NA NA  3  5  8  2  9  8  2  2
```

Explanation: For every column of `m1` we extract the indices of `TRUE` entries in `idx`; we then return the first index of `idx` that is greater than the column number-matched entry in `v1`; if no such number exists, it automatically returns `NA`.

Note: In order for `mapply` to simultaneously loop over columns of `m1` and entries of `v1`, we need to convert `m1` into a `data.frame`.

---

### Sample data

With the above fixed random seed, the sample is data is

```
m1
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[10,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

v1
#[1]  9 10  2  3  6  1  5  6  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
r=10
c=10
set.seed(42)
m1 <- matrix(runif(r*c)>0.5, r, c)
set.seed(314)
v1 <- round(runif(10,1,10))

out = sapply(1:10, function(i) 
{ 
  v = v1[i]
  r = m1[v:10,i]
  j = which(r)[1] + v - 1
})

out
```

My input (reproducible with the seed)

```
> m1
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> v1
 [1] 2 3 8 3 3 4 3 4 6 8
```

My output

```
> out
 [1]  4  6 10  4  4  6  4  6 NA  9
```

Comment: Hmm not really, in this case, the ouput I want would be : 

   4   6  10   4   4   6   4   6   NA  9

Comment: I inverted the lines an columns. I computed on lines not on columns

Answer (score 0):

Get the row/column indices for each `TRUE` using `which`. The code inside `which` uses the combination of `sweep` to calculate if it is a higher row count, and the original TRUE/FALSE `mat` object. Then, these indices are subset to the first match in each column using `match`, which will return `NA` when there is no value in the column.

```
# using Maurits' data

matsel <- which(sweep(row(mat), 2, v1, FUN=`>`) & mat, arr.ind=TRUE)
matsel[,"row"][match(seq_len(ncol(mat)), matsel[,"col"])]
#[1] NA NA  3  5  8  2  9  8  2  2
```

This should scale very nicely too, as it avoids any looping over columns or rows. The only thing to watch would be `matsel` becoming big and hogging your memory as it stores every `TRUE` value's location.